# Understanding custom directives and ngModelController

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

despite the *massive* amounts of examples online, I simply cannot wrap my head around the correct way to use `ng-model` for my custom directive.

I wanted to implement a custom directive that basically is a `<select>` tag, with fixed options that, when selected will set booleans in the model.

In short, I want to be able to use my directive like this:

```
<my-directve ng-model="amodel.options"></my-directive>
```

This should render a select, that when the user selects an option updates `amodel.options` to be set accordingly:

- Option A: `amodel.options.foo = true`, `amodel.options.bar = false`
- Option B: `amodel.options.foo = false`, `amodel.options.bar = true`
- Option C: `amodel.options.foo = true`, `amodel.options.bar = true`

How would I accomplish this? I got this far:

```
angular.module("myApp")
    .directive( "myDirective", function() {
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        replace: true,
        require: "ngModel",
        scope: {},
        template: '<select ng-model="internal">' + 
                    '<option value="0">Option A</option>' +
                    '<option value="1">Option B</option>' +
                    '<option value="2">Option C</option>' +
                  '</select>',
        link: function( scope, element, attr, ngModel ) {

            var mappings = [
                { foo: true, bar: false },
                { foo: false, bar: true },
                { foo: true, bar: true }
            ];

            scope.$watch( "internal", function( val ) {
                ngModel.$modelValue.foo = mappings[val].foo;
                ngModel.$modelValue.bar = mappings[val].bar;
            } );
        },
    };
} );
```

But all this does is give me the error that ng-Model is used redundantly.

I tried going along with various tutorials but none of them worked for me...

How would I do this correctly?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are setting the `replace` attribute to `true`. That means two things:

- The directive's HTML will be replaced by the `template` HTML
- All the attributes/classes from the old element will be migrated to the new one (including the `ng-model`)

This last step is the one that's causing the *"ng-Model is used redundantly"* error.

In order to fix it you just need to remove the `replace` attribute. Also, please have in mind that the `replace` attribute will be [deprecated](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#-replace-deprecated-will-be-removed-in-next-major-release-i-e-v2-0-), so the sooner you stop using it, the better.

**[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/ZWeddOH32OX7aGUH682K?p=preview)**

Comment: Another option, is to do a 2 way binding for the scope to the ngModel value. 
The require : 'ngModel' is just so it will throw an error if no ngModel is used, which as I understand is mandatory here.

That way you bind your internal to the ngModel value in the directive, and the rest is taken care of by angular. 

See plunker: [link](http://plnkr.co/edit/LLgPU9tbzGf8ya9KZ3rB)